# How to specify default path in Ubuntu

Tags: ip

I've an Ubuntu server with Digital Ocean.

Where I can set the default path for the IP address.

Actually I can access to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin/` but not my websites who's here:

```
/var/www/example.ca/public_html
```

In my `000_default.conf`, my conf file is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined    
</VirtualHost>
```

I put an index.php file in `/var/www/html/`, but I have the same error:

```
Not found
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using `/var/www/HTML`? If not, you can change your default Apache config to point to your `example.ca/public_html` directory. Ideally, you would have multiple Apache config files, one for each site, with one acting as a catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

Either change to `/var/www/html/example.ca/public_html` moving the files there to actually be looking in the correct directory you have it configured for, for the files. Or change the `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/` so it will be serving the files up where you try to access them with the first `/var/www/example.ca/public_html`. You need to restart the web server for the configuration changes to take effect `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`. Edit, that is the command to reload on my Debian based systems it may be different in others. And I would add a `http://123.456.789.0` (your IP) or the domain you have, should show you the Apache is working page or that index.html you have put there according to your posting. It needs the `http://123.456.789.0/public_html` as the address to access the files in the `/var/www/html/public_html/` directory of the web server, an index.html file in that directory should just load in a brower as its default homepage for that site.

Comment: Now I see the php it needs to be enabled in Apaches configuration for it this to work. Try a simple .html page to start to confirm it working as intended.